# alguém consegue me ajudar a achar o erro? python!

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

nesse exercício precisa achar a média harmônica mas está dando erro
(o -1 é para parar o x e o x tem que ser entre 1 e 10^3 e o n é o número de notas.) quando tenta rodar, aparece 0. se puderem me ajudar, agradeço

```
media = 0
n = int(input())
while not -1:
    x = int(input())
if 1 <= x <= 10 ** 3:
    media = (n / (1 / x))

print(f'{(media)}')
```

Comment: Me parece que existe um erro de indentação no comando if. Não sei o que você pretende com `while not -1:` pela descrição creio que deva ser `while n <> -1:`. Como você não tem outra leitura da variável `n` caso seja diferente de -1 então entrará em loop infinito. Pelo que entendo de média harmônica você teria que ler `n` valores fazer o acumulado dos inversos e ao final, depois de toda a acumulação, dividir n por este acumulado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alguns erros no seu código:

- while not -1: criava um loop infinito.
- O usuario poderia indicar um quantidade de notas diferente da quantidade que ia passar.
- Não calculava a media usando todos os números

---

Basicamente eu tive que criar um código novo que é bem simples:

1. Criar variável soma.
2. Criar variável n e pedir a quantidade de notas.
3. Laço que pede notas baseado na variável n, e soma as notas numa variável soma.
4. Depois calcula a média e mostra ela na tela.

```py
soma = 0

n = int(input('Digite a quantidade de notas: '))

for i in range(n):
    x = int(input('Valor nota: '))
    soma += (1/x)

media = (n / soma)

print(f'{(media)}')
```

Comment: muito obrigada!!!!!